# When a particle oscillates with simple harmonic motion, the period of the oscillation is

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

When a particle oscillates with simple harmonic motion, the period of the oscillation is...

a) ...directly proportional to the displacement from the origin

b) ...directly proportional to the acceleration of the particle

c) ...independent of the frequency of oscillation

d) ...independent of the amplitude of oscillation

Question taken from CAPE Physics Unit 1 2010 (Q 16)

Comment: what is your guess and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be d). For Simple harmonic motion, the period (and frequency) are independent of the amplitude and the initial phase of the motion.

Note: the period of oscillation IS the inverse of the frequency